# Compiler to compile other java files

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I am trying to compile and run java files from java code.
I have a compiled java class and with this, try to compile java code.
below is my code, but I don't see *.class file in either bin (in eclipse project out put folder) or in source place. Where has gone my *.class file if my compiler success. Or what is the wrong with my code? Trying in below 2 ways:

```
public class CompilerClass {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac com.java.Compileable.java");
             ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javac", "com.java.Compileable.java");
    }  
}
```

Comment: If you're compiling with an IDE, what do the arguments say?  If you're compiling from the command line, you *should* see the .class file in the same directory you compiled in (unless you're doing something a bit more fancy than `javac CompilerClass.java`).

Comment: see there is nothing wrong with the way you do , but the API provides various feature already which you might have to understand or generate , thus this being an already existing solution , choice is yours

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093290/run-a-java-file-using-processbuilder)

Answer (score 2):

well as an alternative you can use java compiler API

```
package javacompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
public class COmpilerHello {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s="C:/Users/MariaHussain/Desktop/hussi.java";
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int result = compiler.run(System.in,System.out,System.err,s);
        System.out.println("Compile result code = " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test it with file you have in the same directory as your `CompilerClass`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac SomeClass.java");
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javac", "SomeClass.java");
}
```

Works fine for me. `SomeClass.java` being in same directory as `CompilerClass`

Ran from command line

Answer (score 0):

you have to state the location of the file. It should be something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac C://JavaProject//SomeClass.java");
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javac", "C://JavaProject//SomeClass.java");
}
```

Comment: I tried this too.  String classLoc ="C://Users//c0328502//Documents//Workspace//Java 1.7//package//com//java//Compileable.java";
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac "+classLoc);
             ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javac", classLoc);

Comment: uhmm i think you have to change directory to the directory that contains the .java file. or just can just put the jar file inside the directory that contain the .java file. this should work